# Which locator strategies can be used to find the element in selenium for the below code

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, xpath-1.0

Which locator to use to find the element yearbook? Tried using LinkText also including all other locators. Seems like not working

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-yearbooks" class="collapsed noRewrite" xpath="1">
    Yearbooks
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i>
    </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the HTML you can use only the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *LinkText*:

  ```
  Yearbooks
  ```
- *Xpath*:

  ```
  "//a[@class='collapsed noRewrite' and contains(@data-target, 'menu-yearbooks')]"
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much :) Xpath is working fine. But linkText is not working.still figuring out why linkText is not working

Comment: Sure. I did :) Any idea why linkText is not working?

Comment: There is a _child_ `<i>` tag for the desired `<a>` tag. As _Selenium_ mocks the `click()` right in the middle of the element, it may not be happening at the intended coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

use this xpath

```
//*[contains(text(),'Yearbooks')]
```

Comment: Tried that too. But getting "org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException"

Comment: Please add some explanation to your query